# Collecting Information From a Variable with An EventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, event-listener

This may be quite a complicated question, but I am making a hack for a game which I have hacked many times before and I have had a request, but I do not know how to work around it.
I am not that advanced at AS3 so please be kind if I fail xD

The request is to make a chat catcher for the game, where all chat is saved. I have been told that I can use an EventListener to do this. I also discovered that

```
Game.chatM
```

Is the linkage (I think that's the correct word for this) for where all of the chat can be found. 
I know that it's a far stretched question, but is there a function which would do something such as this? Like gathering information from this variable?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

What I tried before:

```
package
{
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
 public Class ChatCatcher extends Sprite
 {
 private var Game.chatM:Model;
public function ChatCatcher():void
{
  Game.chatM = new Model();
  Game.chatM.addEventListener(Model.VALUE_CHANGED, onModelChanged);
}
private function onModelChanged(e:Event):void
{
  trace('New Chat Message');
//This is where hopefully chat will be saved
}
}
}
```

Comment: So you are asking us to help u Hack a game? I Dont think so mate ... 
Also what your asking isa very simple task for anyone with the slightest idea of As3. Kids these days calling themselfe hackers, its to sad. expect loads of downvotes!!

Comment: Sorry man, I think you've got the wrong idea :(
I didn't mean to sound like that :P
It's not a 'hack' it's just something which will help with the game, saving a log of the chat isn't hacking in my opinion.
And I admitted that I'm not that good at AS3, I'm just trying to learn. Thanks for being helpful and I don't think I'll be using this site again so don't worry :P

Comment: I think by "hack" he meant that they've added "code smell" to the project, not that they're trying to break into something... @user2228716, there's no code that magically solves your problem. You need to write that code. When a new chat message is created, you add that chat message to an Array. Now you have an array that contains all of the chat messages, and you can use that to display them on screen, or whatever. If you need help w/that, you need to show us the relevant code from your app so someone can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @SunilD.
Thanks for the advice! I think you understand what I was trying to do :)
I have edited my post and added some code I tried using before, but it didn't work- I have no idea why. Is this the right kind of thing I should be looking for though? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a little suspicious.

You incorrectly declare a variable on this line:

```
private var Game.chatM:Model;
```

You shouldn't be declaring variables that have a dot in their name. That should generate an error when you try to compile your code.

I imagine that `Game` is a class, and that in that class you have defined a static property named `chatM` (which is of type `Model`).  If this is the case, then you should do something like this to declare a local instance of the chat model in your class:

```
private var chatModel:Model = Game.chatM;
```

Next, you add an event listener for the event "onModelChanged". **If** the chat model class dispatches such an event when a new chat message is added, then your event listener will get executed.

But all of my guessing here seems to lead me to the conclusion that this is all unnecessary. I'm sure I've misunderstood something... but your intent was to get a list of all the chat messages. And it seems you already have that list (the chat model itself).

If this doesn't help, you should also add the relevant code for your `Model` class and if it exists, the `Game` class... and of course, tell me where my guesses were wrong!

Comment: Ok thanks.
I will try this out later :)
Most of your assumptions seem correct to my knowledge
And to explain why this is needed, even though there is already a chat list, it's because the chat list is limited to only a few messages... people also want a way of saving the chat history to a .txt file but I think I will leave that until after I have sorted this code first. I'll let you know if it works out :)

Comment: Hey man!
I tried correcting what you said but I still haven't had any luck :(
I've decided that this whole thing is very far-stretched and I think I'm just going to leave this one to those who know more about the game and AS3 than me xD But it's being a learning experience and I appreciate your time! :) I set you as my accepted answer :)